# how to restore the file permission of a zip file entry while extracting using minizip API?

Tags: permissions, zip, zlib, unzip

problem statement: ( I am using minizip for reading file entry and data)

How to retrieve the file permission for a zip file entry in a zip file.

I have a zip file and i need to know the file permission of the zip entry inside
the zip file.

The existing minizip API unzGetCurrentFileInfo() returns the unz_file_info struct which has few file metadata, but i am not able to get the file permission using those.

can any one please suggest a way to get the file permission?

Answer (score 1):

The file permission should be in `unz_file_info::external_fa`. The file mode is in `external_fa >> 16`, the file permission in `(external_fa >> 16 ) & 0x01FF` : see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/the-zip-formats-external-file-attribute/14727#14727).